# QClipboard works funny under GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, pyqt4

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QClipboard
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QApplication.clipboard().setText('yo', mode=QClipboard.Clipboard)
input() #wait for input
```

1. When I set `mode=QClipboard.Clipboard` (the default one), it doesn't work. It leaves old data in the clipboard and in the selection clipboard.
2. When I change it to `mode=QClipboard.Selection` (the one specific to X), it replaces *both* selection and primary clipboard with `yo`.

Question: why the "main thing" (`mode` defaults to `QClipboard.Clipboard` after all) doesn't work, while something that should work only conditionally (`QClipboard.supportsSelection()`) does the job? How can I make this work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I can't actually reproduce the problem on my Linux system: it all works fine for me.

However, the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qclipboard.html#notes-for-x11-users) say that the clipboard needs an event-loop on X11:

> the X11 clipboard is event driven, i.e. the clipboard will not
>   function properly if the event loop is not running. Similarly, it is
>   recommended that the contents of the clipboard are stored or retrieved
>   in direct response to user-input events, e.g. mouse button or key
>   presses and releases. You should not store or retrieve the clipboard
>   contents in response to timer or non-user-input events.

So you might be able get your example working on your system by forcing the processing of queued events like this:

```
app.clipboard().setText('yo')
app.processEvents()
input()
```

Obviously that is a contrived "solution", though, and the correct way to do things is to start the event-loop and follow the advice in the docs.